# Xcode doesn't let me initialize values in C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm currently using Stroustrup's book Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++ to pick up C++. One of the topics regards initializing variables. Consider the following example in the book:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "please enter your first_name and age\n";
    string first_name = "???"; // string variable
    // ("???" means "don't know the name")
    int age = -1;              // integer variable (-1 means "don't know the age")
    cin >> first_name >> age;  // read a string followed by an integer
    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

In the code, the variable age is supposed to be initialized as -1. However, in Xcode, when I tried to build and run it, age is set to be 0 when I typed in something that's not an integer for age. For example, if I type in "22 Carlos", the script returns 0 for age. According to the book, I'm supposed to see -1.

I'm using Xcode as my IDE. Does it have something to do with the IDE?